# Loop through array and delete/unset by value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array from a DB query:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [distance] => 14928
        [end] => 5
        [id] => 12
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [distance] => 15645
        [end] => 2
        [id] => 1
    )
```

and an array like this:

```
$locations = array(
            2,3,5
        );
```

What I want to achieve is the following:
Loop through the `$locations` array, do the query and delete integer which is equal to `$dbarray[0]['end']`, then do the foreach again without the unset value from before.
So in this case:

```
$locations before loop = 2,3,5

$locations after loop = 2,3 (because the "end" of the first result is 5)
```

foreach with the "new" `$locations` again

What I have so far:

```
$locations = array(
            2,3,5
        );    
foreach ($locations as $key => $location) {
        $query = $em->createQuery(
          'SELECT l,l.distance,l.end,l.id
           FROM AppBundle:Point l
           WHERE l.start = :startPoint
           AND l.end IN (:endPoint)
           ORDER BY l.distance ASC'
        )
        ->setParameter('startPoint', 1)
        ->setParameter('endPoint', $locations);

 $result = $query->getResult();
    unset($locations[$result[0]['end']]);
    echo $result[0]['end']."<br />";
```

But `echo $result[0]['end']` gives only "5" in every row.

I think my problem is, that the `$locations` in the query are always "2,3,5", isn't it. What is the right approach?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a variable for the `0` in here `$result[0]['end']` (a loop)? Because like this you are using just the position `0`, that's always the same (`5`).

Comment: Well, no, from what I understand/try to achieve the `$result[0]['end']` should always be a different one, as the previous one does not exist anymore?

Comment: I just want to remove just the first one, so in this case `5`

Answer (score 0):

Full solution:

```
$start = 1;
    $locations = array(
        2,3,5,4
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($this->getUser()->getDbuser());
    foreach ($locations as $key => &$location) {
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT l,l.distance,l.end,l.id
               FROM AppBundle:Point l
               WHERE l.start = :startPoint
               AND l.end IN (:endPoint)
               ORDER BY l.distance ASC'
            )
            ->setParameter('startPoint', 1)
            ->setParameter('endPoint', $locations);

        $result = $query->getResult();
        // Remove from array
        $locations = array_diff($locations,array($result[0]['end']));



        echo $result[0]['end']."<br />";
    }
    // Last one in the array
    echo $result[1]['end']."<br />";
```

Probably not the cleanest way, but works for me.